# Python 2.7.1 and Python 2.7.1+ on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python, interpreter

I am having two different machines running Ubuntu 11.04 with Python 2.7.1 installed. However, on one machine with

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
```

I am able to press the up arrow to load the previous commands, left and right to move toward the left and right and such during interactive interpreter.

But on machine running

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, May  9 2011, 13:46:03) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
```

I am unable to do so. So I am wondering what really caused the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Would you please elaborate more on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second installation of Python 2.7.1 seems to have been compiled later. I'm guessing it was compiled from source. The libreadline-dev(*) package must be installed so support for readline can be included when Python is compiled.

(*) The actual package name for your particular version of Linux will vary.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your answer! It worked :D I had to recompile it after installing libreadline-dev